# How to configure Jboss with Spring security PKI 509 login?

Tags: spring, jboss, spring-security

I am new to Jboss and Spring. But do understand how the PKI 509 works and know to generate the needed certificates for the same. The trouble is setting up of Jboss with Spring security PKI 509 based login. 
 What would be a good tutorial to achieve the same...

thanks

Nohsib

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you'll need to enable SSL for JBoss, using your servers certificate as the keystore, and an associated truststore for the CA Cert chains which signed the servers cert, and any chains which are used to sign the client certs you wish to interact with your server. You'll also want to set the clientAuth to either "true" (clients must have a cert) or "want" (allowing fall back to another auth method like BASIC in case the client doesn't have a client cert):

- http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/2.1.x/ssl-howto.html (i'm not sure out of date this is, i use Tomcat rather than JBoss)

Now within your web application you'll need to configure Spring and enable the X509 Pre Auth filter. This pulls the client's DN from the servlet request attribute `javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate`. A portion of this DN can then be extracted (the CN for example), and this is then used in conjunction with a `UserDetailsService` implementation to lookup (in a DB or via a WS call for example) the users details.

Beyond this, you can provide authorization based upon the users details such as roles, groups, orgs etc.

- http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/x509.html

A simple Spring configuration for this might look something like this (untested and purely from memory of the many times i've written something like this):

```
<http:http>
  <!-- X509 Filter to extract PKI CN field as the users name, which is then 
       passed to the userService to lookup their details (such as roles) -->
  <http:x509 subject-principal-regex="CN=(.*?)," 
       user-service-ref="userService"/>

  <!-- filter all traffic to any URL, user must be authenticated and had the specified
       role in their UserDetails object -->
  <intercept-url pattern='/**' access='ROLE_USER' />
</http:http>

<!-- Custom user service that calls out to Restful web service to acquire user 
     details information, based upon the PKI Certs CN field -->
<beans:bean id="userService"
  class="com.domain.security.user.ws.RestfulUserService">
</beans:bean>
```

Finally, it's a whole lot of text to read, but the documentation for Spring Security is pretty good, and provides examples and insight to what's going on behind the scenes - i would highly recommend reading (it's where i learnt this all!):

- http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity.html